# python skipping the next index in a loop if a condition is met in 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new at python so I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

I have 2 lists with the same amount of values.
I want to compare the values of each index from the 2 lists i.e index 1 of player 1 to player 2, index 2 of player 1 to player 2 and so on.

if index 1 of player 1 to player 2 values are matched add 2 points and skip the next index on both lists. Having trouble figuring out how to skip the next index if both values of index 1 are a matched. Please help.

This is my code:

```
player1 = ['yes', 'deal', 'no', 'no deal', 'no', 'deal']
player2 = ['yes', 'no deal', 'yes', 'deal', 'no', 'deal']

count = 0
skip_count = 0

for i in range(len(player1)):
    if player1[i] == player2[i]:
        count += 2
        skip_count = 0
    else:
        count += 1
```

when I print count, it doesn't skip as I want it to any thoughts?

Comment: you can use `continue` to skip iteration. So yes and yes will be compared but deal and no deal will be skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create a generator that will iterate over the two lists in pairs. When the condition is met you can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to generate the next pair in the iterator "skipping" over that pair:

```
player1 = ['yes', 'deal', 'no', 'no deal', 'no', 'deal']
player2 = ['yes', 'no deal', 'yes', 'deal', 'no', 'deal']
pairs = zip(player1, player2)
count = 0
for a, b in pairs:
    if a == b:
        count += 2
        next(pairs, None)
    elif a != b:
        count += 1
        comp = next(pairs, True)
        if 'deal' and 'deal' in comp:
            count += -2
            break
        elif 'no deal' and 'deal' in comp:
            count += -1
            break
        elif 'no deal' and 'no deal' in comp:
            count += 0
            break
        else:
            break
    else:
        break
print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you Iain! Your application worked best for what I'm trying to achieve. Problem is, I keep getting the calculation of the count variable wrong at the 2nd part of the code. Any suggestion?

Comment: Watch out, `if 'deal' and 'deal' in comp:` is equivalent to `if bool('deal') and ('deal' in comp):`. If you want to check that comp contains two instances of "deal", you should try a different approach.

Comment: yes, I want to check that comp contains two instances of "deal": Any suggestion? @kevin

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop. One could have better control over the sentinel value (or) iterator value (the variable that controls entry to the loops implementation).

```py
player1 = ['yes', 'deal', 'no', 'no deal', 'no', 'deal']
player2 = ['yes', 'no deal', 'yes', 'deal', 'no', 'deal']

cap = len(player1)
i = 0 # sentinel

while i < cap:
    if player1[i] == player2[i]:
        i += 1 # handle the skip
    i += 1 # handle next

''' In simpler terms
while i < cap:
    if player1[i] == player2[i]:
        i += 2
    else :
        i += 1
'''
```

Comment: thank you but I guess I'm having trouble understanding where the point/count is being if i represents the index and cap for total amount. Thank you nonetheless!